# Very ample imply immersion

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It is known that an invertible sheaf on a $A$-scheme $X$ is by definition very ample (on $A$) if there is an immersion $i:X\to\mathbb{P}^n_A$  such that $\mathcal{L}=i^*(\mathcal{O}(1))$.

Is it true reciprocally that if an $A$-morphism $\varphi:X\to\mathbb{P}^n_A$ is such that $\mathcal{L}:=\varphi^*(\mathcal{O}(1))$ with $\mathcal{L}$ is very ample then $\varphi$ is automatically an immersion?

My question comes from the proof of proposition V.2.2 (line 11) where it seems such a reasoning is used.

Comment: Take a finite map from $\mathbb{P}^1$ to itself.

Comment: Ok: one takes some $\varphi:\mathbb{P}^1\to\mathbb{P}^1$ finite. Then $\varphi^*\mathcal{O}(1)$ is very ample: why? It is an invertible sheaf so it is a $\mathcal{O}(k)$ and to conclude we have to prove that $k\geqslant 0$

Comment: I will leave you to check $k=\deg \phi$.

Comment: Ok, in general $\mathcal{O}(1)=\mathcal{O}(H)$ with $H$ an hyperplan so here $\mathcal{O}(1)=\mathcal{O}(Q)$ with $Q$ a (closed) point, so that $\varphi^*\mathcal{O}(1)=\varphi^*(Q)=\varphi\left(\sum\limits_{P\mapsto Q}e_P P\right)$ with $e_P$ the ramification index. If $\mathcal{O}(\sum e_P P)\simeq\mathcal{O}(k)$ then $\sum e_P P\sim kH$ then the degree are the same so that $k=\sum_P e_P=\deg(\varphi)$

Comment: @GabrielSoranzo: Note that $i^{-1}$ and $i^*$ differ - the first is topological inverse image and the second is inverse image as $\mathcal{O}_X$-module.

Comment: @hm2020: where did I confuse the two?

Comment: A ok in the question! I make the change, thanks!